# Forloop, Conditional Statements, Storing Data

Tags: r

What i am trying to accomplish in the forloop and am still having difficulty with:

```
prb[i]=(prb[i-1]*ER)+b[i]
prb[1]=(prb[0]*ER)+b[1]
prb[2]=(prb[1]*ER)+b[2]
```

and then output prb[1,2,3....] from the left hand side of the equation.

Also, defining SS to reflect prb at the previous time step (i.e. (prb-1))

I have attempted to save the results from my forloop in the empty vectors. However, the values outputted into the vectors are the same values(i.e. from the first iteration) and it doesn't appear to be having the additive affect I am attempting. Somethings appears to be wrong with the logic of my code. I would like for the values from b[i] to be used in b[i+1]  for the next run of the forloop. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to problem? Best!

Matthew

```
#Parameters
c=0.2
A=5
d=8
d0=5
s=0.5
e=0.1
p=0.6
ER=e/A

#Colonization Equation Probabilities
C2 = c*A*exp(-d*s/d0)               #ML to SS

#Empty Vectors
l=vector(mode="numeric", length=100) #open vectors to store the different probability values from the forloop
b=vector(mode="numeric", length=100) 
prb=(l*ER) + b     #total probability of SS being colonized 

#Island States
ML=1                    
SS=prb         
n.I=c(ML, SS)   

#Forloop and Conditional Statements

for(i in 2:101) {

  (SS[i]=prb[i-1])
  (prb[i]=(l[i]*ER)+b[i])

  if (SS < 1 ) { 
    (l[i]=prb[i-1])
 } else if(SS < 1){
    b[i]=C2
  }   
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop does not use iterator variable, `i` and then `prb` is initialized as product of empty vectors, and then *C1* and *C3* are constants. How are elements in empty vectors to change?

Comment: does it help if you move the definitions for `prb` and `prb.T` inside the loop?

Comment: Moving the prb and prb.T formulas doesn't appear to help

Comment: What is the purpose of SS?  As it is an unchanging vector it seems odd for the if () statement using it to be in the loop. I'm sure that's related to your problem.

Comment: @Peter Ellis I was attempting to make SS an open vector from values 0 through 1 that reflected the output values from prb (forloop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it. My observations are:

- First of all, in R, vector indices start from 1 not 0.
- So SS=prb[0:1] yields prb[0] which is just 0.
- Since to execute the line for populating prb is conditional on SS being >= 1, you can never run this line with this condition. When prb[1] is not 1 or larger, you cannot alter it so there is a vicious circle.
- Even if you can run it by satisfying the condition (a different one of course), since for the first iteration prb[0] is non existent so prb[0]*ER just yields numeric(0), which is an empty vector item!

So first you should modify your vector indices, then you should modify your condition so that it allows for a jump start.

Comment: l was attempting to make SS an open vector from values 0 through 1 that reflected the output values from prb (forloop). I can  change the forloop starting point from (i in 1:100) to (i in 2:101) which seems to fix the second problem you addressed with my code. Thanks for the help!